# Swift, adding a class array into a variable does not update array content in original class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm new to IOS so forgive me for my coding mistakes. I'm facing an issue where I have a tableView Controller with two sections. The first section has a button, when clicked, appends data into an array and deletes it's own row in the first section (i did this as there are extra non related rows in the first section). The number of rows in the second section is based upon array.count.

My issue is that I tried begin/end update, and it still doesn't work. Whenever I run the code below and run the startNewDay function (when the button is clicked), this error occurs:

'attempt to insert row 0 into section 1, but there are only 0 rows in section 1 after the update'

This doesn't make any sense, as I appended the array already before I inserted the new rows. The array was empty before I appended it. Shouldn't there be the same number of rows in the second section as array.count?

Table View Delegate code:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if dataModel.lists[0].dayHasStarted == false {
            return 2
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    } else {
        if itemDoneCount == dataModel.lists[0].item.count && dataModel.lists[0].doneButtonVisible {
            return dataModel.lists[0].item.count + 1
        } else {
            return dataModel.lists[0].item.count
        }
    }
}
```

startNewDay button function when pressed:

```
@IBAction func startNewDayDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    dataModel.lists[0].dayHasStarted = true
    dataModel.lists[0].startDate = NSDate()
    addItemButton.enabled = !addItemButton.enabled

    // deleting start new day button

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()

    // Inserting new array elements and rows into 2nd section

    let ritualsArray = dataModel.lists[0].rituals
    var itemsArray = dataModel.lists[0].item
    itemsArray.appendContentsOf(ritualsArray)

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    var insertRitualsArray = [NSIndexPath]()

    for item in itemsArray {
        let itemIndex = itemsArray.indexOf(item)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: itemIndex!, inSection: 1)
        insertRitualsArray.append(indexPath)
    }

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertRitualsArray, withRowAnimation: .Top)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

## **SOLVED**

The problem of this code is not at all related to the previous title of this thread, which may be misleading to people having the same issue as mine. Hence, I will be changing it. The previous title (for the curious) was :

"tableView.begin/end update not updating number of rows in section"

Just for others who might come across this issue, the issue isn't in the tableView delegate, nor is it in reloading the tableview data. For readability, I placed both dataModel.list[0].item into itemsArray and dataModel.list[0].item into ritualsArray. This apparently updates the itemsArray when appended but not the initial dataModel.list[0].item instead, which caused the second section in the tableView not to load the new number of rows, causing the error when inserting rows into non-existant rows.

Hence instead of:

```
    let ritualsArray = dataModel.lists[0].rituals
    var itemsArray = dataModel.lists[0].item
    itemsArray.appendContentsOf(ritualsArray)
```

this solved it:

```
dataModel.list[0].item += dataModel.list[0].rituals
```

Hope it helps any beginner like me out there that comes across this issue.

## **Latest update**

I found out recently that an array is of value type, and not reference type. Hence placing an array into a variable makes a copy of that array instead of serving as a placeholder for the original array.

Beginner mistake opps.

Comment: You don't need `begin/endUpdates` for a single insert/delete operation. It's only useful for multiple **different** operations for example move and delete simultaneously.

Comment: Oh, alright I'll keep that in mind. It's just unnecessary code and does not interfere with anything right? Sorry, I'm new and still learning!

Comment: Yes, in your code you can remove all `begin/endUpdates` lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are receiving means that the datasource contains a different number of items to however many there would be after inserting or deleting rows. This probably means that the data are not being inserted into your datasource array, or that the data do not match the criteria in the if statements in your numberOfRowsInSection function. To troubleshoot this, you should log the contents of the datasource array after modifying it to check what its contents are. If they are what you are expecting (I.e. The data have been added correctly) then the issue is in the way you are evaluating its contents to establish the number of rows. If the contents are not what you are expecting, then the issue is in the way you are inserting the data into the datasource array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It worked, apparently it did not append into my array correctly, which i found odd. Placing dataModel.list[0].item into the variable itemArray and itemArray.appendContentsOf it does not update dataModel.list[0].item array. Do you know why is that so? My new code: `dataModel.lists[0].item += dataModel.lists[0].rituals`

Comment: I am not familiar with Swift. However, this is expected behaviour in Objective C. If you put dataModel.list[0].item into itemArray and then append to itemArray, then itemArray is a copy of dataModel.list[0].item. It contains the same objects as the original array, but changes made to the copy will not be reflected in the original array. You would have to set dataModel.list[0].item to itemArray after changing itemArray so that the original array reflects the content of the updated array. Alternatively (and easier) you can do what you have done - update dataModel.lists[0].item directly.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you detailed answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after deleting a row. It seems that if 
numberOfRowsInSection is not coherent  (equal to last value -1) this error appears. 
I see that there's a condition in your numberOfRowsInSection, this is perhaps the culprit

Comment: Hi Frederic, firstly, thanks for the help! I solved my issue by not putting both arrays into variables (itemArray and ritualsArray and append one into the other) but instead appending it straight away using the += operator, like so: `dataModel.lists[0].item += dataModel.lists[0].rituals`.